# Least distance from a point to an area

Tags: algorithm, graphics, computational-geometry

I am trying to find a point (P2) in a closed area that has the minimum distance to a point (P1). The area is built of homogenous pixels, it is not shaped perfectly and it is not necessarily convex. This is basically a problem of reaching an area from the shortest path.

The whole space is a stored in the form of a bitmap in the memory. What is the best method to find P2? Should I go with random search (optimization) methods? Optimization methods do not give the exact minimum but they are faster than brute forcing every pixel of the area. I need to perform thousands of these decisions in a few seconds.

The MinX,MinY,MaxX,MaxY of the area is available.

[image: Peroblem]

Thanks.

Comment: Is the shape convex? otherwise solution might not be unique. You could find some answers here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170731/shortest-distance-between-two-shapes

Comment: If you could also explain the implementation requirement of this logic, a feasible solution can be thought of.

Comment: How are the points in the area stored? Do we have fast access to the boundary points (the only ones that are relevant)?

Comment: May we assume the area is convex?

Comment: @chepner I added the information. The whole space is stored in a memory bitmap.

Comment: @MurtuzaKabul this is a graphics program and the whole space is stored in a memory bitmap.

Comment: @Maxx The shape is not necessarily convex. Thanks for the link. I'll see the articles suggested in that question.

Comment: I'm not sure if you already thought of this, but you only have to consider the perimeter of the area. You can then proceed to estimate the perimeter with fewer points to get faster computations, as anon pointed out in one of the answers. You could possibly apply occlusion culling, but this is likely more expensive than considering all boundary points.

Comment: Maybe I'm unfamiliar with the domain in which you're working, but what exactly do you mean by shaped "perfectly" and "homogenous" pixel?

Comment: @Jerry: it is a map of an area drawn by a bitmap editor. As such, the circumference may not be composed of lines, arcs etc. It can have any possible (including jagged, brush...) form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my code, it's a discrete version using discrete coordinates:

Hint: the method I used to find the circumference of the Area is simple, it's like how do you know the beach from the land ? answer: the beach is covered by Sea from one side, so in my graph matrix, NULL reference is Sea, Points are Land!

Class Point:

```
class Point
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point (int X, int Y)
    {
        this.x = X;
        this.y = Y;
    }
}
```

Class Area:

```
class Area
{
    public ArrayList<Point> points;

    public Area ()
    {
        p = new ArrayList<Point>();
    }
}
```

Discrete Distance Utility Class:

```
class DiscreteDistance
{

    public static int distance (Point a, Point b)
    {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b.x - a.x,2), Math.pow(b.y - a.y,2))
    }

    public static int distance (Point a, Area area)
    {
        ArrayList<Point> cir = circumference(area);
        int d = null;

        for (Point b : cir)
        {
            if (d == null || distance(a,b) < d)
            {
                d = distance(a,b);
            }
        }

        return d;
    }

    ArrayList<Point> circumference (Area area)
    {
        int minX = 0;
        int minY = 0;
        int maxX = 0;
        int maxY = 0;

        for (Point p : area.points)
        {
            if (p.x < minX) minX = p.x;
            if (p.x > maxX) maxX = p.x;
            if (p.y < minY) minY = p.y;
            if (p.y > maxY) maxY = p.y;
        }

        int w = maxX - minX +1;
        int h = maxY - minY +1;

        Point[][] graph = new Point[w][h];

        for (Point p : area.points)
        {
            graph[p.x - minX][p.y - minY] = p;
        }

        ArrayList<Point> cir = new ArrayList<Point>();

        for (int i=0; i<w; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<h; j++)
            {
                if ((i > 0 && graph[i-1][j] == null)
                  || (i < (w-1) && graph[i+1][j] == null)
                  || (j > 0 && graph[i][j-1] == null)
                  || (i < (h-1) && graph[i][j+1] == null))
                {
                    cir.add(graph[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        return cir;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Khaled, Thanks. I guess I need to have the edges in the Area ArrayList, right? And the area should be a polygon?

Comment: First, to thank me up-vote my solution .. basically, I'm doing a linear minimization over distance(point, circumference) .. if you want to find minimal distance between two areas, you simply have to do linear minimization over distance(circumferenceA, circumferenceB)

Comment: So what does the "ArrayList<Point> points" in the Area class contain?

Comment: that should've been obvious, An area is made of points .. check back the figure you provided in your post, it says "Area (set of pixels)", basically here we use Point instead of Pixel

Comment: So the edges of the area should be extracted before and put in the ArrayList. In case the area is well shaped, it would be possible to find and store the edges, otherwise (worst case) we need to put the whole borderline in the array. Thanks.

Comment: Taking the points of the circumference is an optimization, instead of going over all points of the Area .. the shape doesn't have to be well-formed in any form either

Comment: Also, the method I used to find the circumference of the Area is simple, it's like how do you know the beach from the land ? answer: the beach is covered by Sea from one side, so in my graph matrix, NULL reference is Sea, Points are Land!

Comment: Khaled, thanks for your interesting solution. In this case, the area is made of Pixels and the edge points are unknown. But it's still possible to extract them.

Comment: Yes, because they are adjacent to a Null Reference in graph matrix

Comment: If you're going to loop over each point in the area at least three times, why not just calculate the distance to each one once and record the min? Taking the square root and squaring are not so costly compared to what you are doing to make it worthwhile.

Comment: you're right, but if you're going to re-use the same area more than 3 times .. it's more optimal, to pre-calculate the circumference

Comment: @jerry I use fixed areas for a simulation in which the decision is being taken hundred thousands of times. So finding keeping the circumference is better.

Comment: @wmac I want to make sure I understand you correctly. You have one fixed area `A` and many points `p1,p2,p3,...,pn`, you would like to find points `a1,a2,a3,...,an` such that `ai` is the point in `A` closest to `pi`. Is this correct? Also, does your area `A` have any holes?

Comment: @Jerry: consider a simulation in which large number of objects travel from their position (that might be different) to the specified area. The simulation map is stored in a Bitmap form. We want to find the shortest path to the area from object's current position. Let's say the area does not have holes (since that will ease finding the circumference).

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer, just to make it clear. [No one has to *first* upvote you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167155/comments-asking-for-upvotes-accepts) ;)

Answer (score 1):

We have to assume you know or can easily find at least one pixel address (x0,y0) inside the area.  The fastest solution will certainly be to search from this pixel in a straight line, say in the plus x direction Alternately, since you have a bounding box, pick the compass point toward the nearest boundary and go in that direction.

When you find the edge of the region, search depth first along the boundary.  *For general polygons with self-intersections and/or holes, this will have to be a complete and carefully implemented DFS maintaining a set of already-visited vertices.*  Only if the polygon is simple will it suffice to remember only the last-visited pixel to avoid doubling back over what's already searched.

During the DFS, compute the distance squared to p1 for each boundary pixel and track the minimum.

Note, if you are really pressed for performance this distance squared can be updated incrementally to replace multiplications with additions.  I.e. if you know `d2=(x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2` and then increment `x2` by 1 to take the next step around the boundary, the new squared distance is

```
((x2+1) - x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 = d2 + 2(x2 - x1) + 1
```

So you can update `d2` with `d2 += 2(x2 - x1) + 1`.  The multiplication by 2 is of course just a left shift, so this is very cheap. There are similar very cheap updates for steps in each direction.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to set for an approximate solution by first canculating a triangulation of the area; afterwards, only the corners of the triangles have to be checked. This approach could be beneficial especially if in the many evaluations you plan for, the outside point changes but the shape itself does not change.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the center of the rect of the area, and use a triangle between the two points to find the angle, and then use a function f(x) = mx + b to do the pixel walk until you find a pixel of the area to calculate the distance, and then rotate the angle until you find the shortest path.