# Path finding A to B at different floors

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, a-star

I have this problem on what algorithm or approach will I consider to solve a particular problem of finding a path from point A to point B wherein both points aren't on the same plane (are on different floor / level of the compound - may not be on the same building).

I am considering both [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) and [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) algorithms. Yet basing from this algorithm's this only (correct me if I am wrong) only focus on a single map plot. Having different map plots (due to many floors and many buildings) can have a different story for both of the said algorithm.

In line with the difficulty, I have devised a format to all of my maps to follow consistency of data. In each map there exists the data for the building name, floor number, and the sections each floor may have and with the floor plan (converted into a two-dimensional single character array). For example (Both maps are on different files):

```
//MainFloor1             //MainFloor2
Main                    Main
1st                     2nd
1:Wall                  1:Wall
2:Door                  2:Door
3:Elevator              3:Elevator
#                       4:Room1
1111441111              5:Room2
1        1              #
1        1              1111441111
1        1              1552  2441
1111221111              1551  1441
#                       1551  1441
//End-MainFloor1        1111221111
                        #
                        //End-MainFloor2
```

From the given map if I want to consider going from Point A (Below the 1st '2' from lest of MainFloor1) to Point B (The first '4' from the top-left of MainFloor2) would return me the result.

```
// X is the path from Point A to Point B
1111X41111 1111X41111
1   X    1 1552XXXB41 
1   X    1 1551  1441 
1   X    1 1551  1441 
1111A21111 1111221111
```

What approach will I consider or take to produce such result from the given map inputs?

Thanks

Comment: If after a while you don't get an answer here, you might try [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait for any comment or wait for this thread be transfer to gamedev [though this thread isn't game related].

Comment: Path finding algorithms are very common in games (to make the enemies move through buildings or around obstacles), that's why I suggested it.

Comment: I don't get it. graphs (which both A* and dijkstra work on) have no sense of "planes". if some nodes are connected to 8 others (all nodes "around it" plane wise) and others are connected to 9 or more (all nodes around it and others above/below it) neither algorithm will care..

Comment: @Virtlink: if that case it might be, but this problem solves a problem to guide people on smartphone (without the use of GPS) from point A to point B.

Comment: @Oren: kindly take note both map of MainFloor1 and MainFloor2 are not on the same graph, there are of different graphs.

Comment: if you know the connection points between the two "maps" you can easily create a combined graph from them.

Comment: @Oren: okay, but what if I have to add several maps for every floor? And also I have to add a link from building A to building B at a particular floor in such way Point 1 from building A could route to Point 2 on building B, combining all maps wouldn't be an option.

Comment: Path finding algorithm depends on how the finder seek the destination, is it through local perception using sensors, or using a GPS location using a map like what your example shows, or a simulation of an existing perception system, or it's artificial like graph search

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer: true, but this thread won't be using GPS location and the map would be retrieve from files using the format shown above. If there's another way to make a path from Point A located on Building A at a certain floor to Point B located on Building C at a certain floor, I am welcome for suggestions.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you obtain location, but do you have current_location at time i, if you also have current_floor then it's better .. then the solution is simple

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer: I'm sorry but I can't follow what you've said, can you explain it further?

Comment: check my solution for single floor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A*, BFS, and others are all algorithms that work on [graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29).  Your problem can be considered a graph where there is an edge between two nodes *(vertices)* if they are adjacent and on the same floor, **or** if they represent the same elevator but on different floors.

Note that you can build the graph explicitly in memory, but you don't have to - you can simply treat it like one from your pathfinder's perspective.

Comment: Building the graph explicitly in memory would help find the path from point A to point B. But creating adjacency between edge nodes wherein this edge nodes signify the relationship between the current floor and the floor above and beneath it with exclusion of elevators is the problem I'm seeking for a solution.

Comment: @Dr.Java: I'm sorry, I don't see the problem.  You can trivially do exactly what you said, exactly how you said it:  just create an edge between two floors whenever their elevator-tiles are connected.  What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am having the problem on how I could create the relationship to the different floors.

Answer (score 2):

```
// X is the path from Point A to Point B

1111B11111
1   X    1
1   X    1
1   X    1
1111A11111
```

Here is a solution that works on a single floor only,

The robot can move only in 4 directions ..

**The proposed solution is BFS (Breadth-First Search) using Taboo List**

Using these classes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549604/2128327

```
class Floor
{
    public ArrayList<Point> points;

    public int minX, minY, maxX, maxY;

    public Floor ()
    {
        p = new ArrayList<Point>();
    }
}
```

Solution for single floor:

```
class PathFinder
{
    public static Floor floor;

    public static Point location;

    public static void search (Floor floor, Point dest, Point initial_location)
    {
        QueueSet<Point> fringe = new QueueSet<Point>();

        ArrayList<Point> taboo = new ArrayList<Point>();

        boolean solution_found = false;

        Point p = null;

        fringe.enqueue(initial_location);

        while (fringe.size() > 0)
        {
            p = fringe.dequeue();
            taboo.add(p);

            if (p.x == dest.x && p.y == dest.y)
            {
                    solution_found = true;
                    break;
            }

            if (p.x > floor.minX && !taboo.contains(new Point(p.x-1,p.y))
                fringe.enqueue(new Point(p.x-1,p.y));

            if (p.x < floor.maxX && !taboo.contains(new Point(p.x+1,p.y))
                fringe.enqueue(new Point(p.x+1,p.y));

            if (p.y > floor.minY && !taboo.contains(new Point(p.x,p.y-1))
                fringe.enqueue(new Point(p.x,p.y-1));

            if (p.y < floor.maxY && !taboo.contains(new Point(p.x,p.y+1))
                fringe.enqueue(new Point(p.x,p.y+1));
        }

        // taboo list represent the path taken so far

        fringe.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but this only handles a single floor path finding. How could I handle multiple floors and multiple buildings? But basing from this answer (correct me if I'm wrong), I'm going to plot another point A and B on each of the floors and buildings to pass?

Comment: You can modify the above code, if destination is not on the current floor, head for the elevator\gate .. Bare at mind that this solution is a Blind Search, you need to define a Heuristic (ex: distance to destination) & use a PriorityQueue instead

Comment: .. then you'd have hierarchal concept on Heuristic (ex: if current point & destination point are on different buildings, then take distance between the two buildings in account; same concept with floors too)

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer, [please stop asking for upvotes. That's just unnecessary noise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167155/213383)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your implementation, it should be possible to combine several maps in one single graph with interconnections at specific points. I think that's the idea that BlueRaja has been trying to explain.

The A* algorithm (and Djkstra as well) is based on querying edges leaving nodes of graph, and their respective weights. In most languages, this graph object can be abstracted to an opaque type and a set of operations to query its content: for instance, in Java, the set of operations would constitute an interface, and the opaque type the class implementing the interface casted back to that interface. Other languages may provide this mechanism differently, as for instance in ML dialects with structures, signatures, and functors.

If the algorithm is constructed around this interface, it should be very easy to replace the floor map class implementing the graph interface by another type whose content would be several floor maps, and the necessary functions or methods to convey uniformly regular edges within a floor, and special edges between floors. With that new building class, one could imagine encapsulating (following the same pattern) several instances of buildings, with the ad hoc code to provide building inner and outer connections as graph edges.

The A* algorithm implementation, if well abstracted, should be completely orthogonal to the implementation details of the graph, node, and edge, and it should be capable of being executed with any object supporting the graph interface.

For instance, here is a possible interface for Graph:

```
interface Graph<Node, Scalar> {
    int compare(Node n1, Node n2);
    Collection<Node> getNeighbourgs(Node n);
    Scalar getCost(Node n1, Node n2);
}
```

where `Node` is a node in the graph, and `Scalar` the type representing the cost (or distance) between nodes.

```
class Cell<Position extends Comparable<Position>> implements Comparable<Cell<Position>> {
    private Position position;
    public Cell(Position p){
         position = p;
    }
    Position getPosition(){
         return position;
    }
    int compareTo(Cell<Position> c){
         return position.compareTo(c.getPosition());
    }
}

abstract class WorldCell extends Cell<Position> {
    public WorldCell(Position p){
        super(p);
    }
}

abstract class World implements Graph<WorldCell, Integer> {
     private Building [] buildings;
     private HashMap<WorldCell, LinkedList<WorldCell>> gateways;
     int compare(WorldCell n1, WorldCell n2){
           return n1.compareTo(n2);
     }
     public Collection<WorldCell> getNeighbourgs(WorldCell c){
           // build the collections of cells from the building it belongs to
           // and the gateways (connections between buildings
     }
     Scalar getCost(Node n1, Node n2){
           // compute the cost based on the node positions in space
     }       
}


abstract class Building implements Graph<WorldCell, Integer> {
     private Floor [] floors;
     private HashMap<WorldCell, LinkedList<WorldCell>> gateways;
     int compare(WorldCell n1, WorldCell n2){
           return n1.compareTo(n2);
     }
     public Collection<WorldCell> getNeighbourgs(WorldCell c){
           // build the collections of cells from the floor it belongs to
           // and the gateways (connections between floors)
     }
```

This partial class set provides a initial sketching of a multiple implementation for a `Graph`. The `Floor` class would replicate more or less the same code as in `World` or `Building` with an array of `Room` class instances.

Of course, we can see a pattern of "Russian dolls" like containers here, which could certainly be abstracted somehow, but the purpose of this example is to show how the same interface can be implemented by different parts of the world you intent to model.